# Parsing a live SOAP data stream with PHP

Tags: php, soap

I have a enterprise application that provides a fairly robust API for gathering data.  Currently I am querying each user that I want an update on in a loop every second.  However the new API documentation now provides a live stream of all changes on all users.  I am wondering how I can parse this live data as it comes with php. Here are some details:

The data is requested via  a SOAP request, and I am using PHP to make these requests like this (example of session initiation with a unique ID returned):

```
//Get a session ID for this user for the shoretel WEBAPI
$soap_url = 'http://11.11.11.11:8070/ShoreTelWebSDK?wsdl';
$client = new SOAPClient($soap_url, array( 'proxy_host' => '11.11.11.11', 'proxy_port' => 8070, 'trace' => 1 ) );
$client = new SoapClient($soap_url);

$header = new SoapHeader('http://www.ShoreTel.com/ProServices/SDK/Web');
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$registered_string = $client->RegisterClient(array(
                'clientName' => '11.11.11.211'
            )); 
$registered_string = get_object_vars($registered_string);   
$session =  $registered_string['RegisterClientResult'];
```

The new method allows me to specify a time period.  For example if I would like to get all events for 1 minute the call will initiate, wait one minute, then return all of the events that occured during that minute.

What I would like to do is grab each event as it occurs, and insert it into a database. Is this something that I can accomplish with PHP, or do I need to look to another language to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the goal is to "stream a SOAP reponse" with a "timeout" and/or in an "interval"?

I suggest to override the `SoapClient __doRequest()` method and implement a custom connection via `fsockopen()` and stream the data with `stream_get_contents()`.
Now you get a stream of XML data and what you want is in the middle of it.
You would have to extract the XML envelope or parts of it, probably using string functions or by using `preg_match` to fetch the inner content.

The following code provides a SoapClientTimeout class, where the timeout is set via `stream_set_timeout()`. This is for use-case, when the server has slow responses and you want to make sure, when to end listening.

I suggest to play around with it and tweak the timeout behavior on the socket. 
Because, what you want is to stop listening after a while (interval fetch).
So, you cloud try to combine timeout with blocking, to stop reading from the stream after a while:

```
$timeout = 60; // seconds
stream_set_blocking($socket, true);
stream_set_timeout($socket, $timeout);
```

When you have a stream, which blocks after 1 minute and closes,
you need a loop (with a solid exit condition) triggering the next request.

---

```
class SoapClientTimeout extends SoapClient
{    
    public function __construct ($wsdl, $options = null)
    {
        if (!$options) $options = [];

        $this->_connectionTimeout = @$options['connection_timeout'] ?: ini_get ('default_socket_timeout');
        $this->_socketTimeout = @$options['socket_timeout'] ?: ini_get ('default_socket_timeout');
        unset ($options['socket_timeout']);

        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    }

    /**
     * Override parent __doRequest and add "timeout" functionality.
     */
    public function __doRequest ($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
    {
        // fetch host, port, and scheme from url.
        $url_parts = parse_url($location);

        $host = $url_parts['host'];
        $port =  @$url_parts['port'] ?: ($url_parts['scheme'] == 'https' ? 443 : 80);
        $length = strlen ($request);

        // create HTTP SOAP request.
        $http_req = "POST $location HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $http_req .= "Host: $host\r\n";
        $http_req .= "SoapAction: $action\r\n";
        $http_req .= "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        $http_req .= "Content-Length: $length\r\n";
        $http_req .= "\r\n";
        $http_req .= $request;

        // switch to SSL, when requested
        if ($url_parts['scheme'] == 'https') $host = 'ssl://'.$host;

        // connect
        $socket = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->_connectionTimeout);

        if (!$socket) {
            throw new SoapFault('Client',"Failed to connect to SOAP server ($location): $errstr");
        }

        // send request with socket timeout
        stream_set_timeout($socket, $this->_socketTimeout);
        fwrite ($socket, $http_req);

        // start reading the response.
        $http_response = stream_get_contents($socket);

        // close the socket and throw an exception if we timed out.
        $info = stream_get_meta_data($socket);
        fclose ($socket);
        if ($info['timed_out']) {
            throw new SoapFault ('Client', "HTTP timeout contacting $location");
        }

        // the stream contains XML data
        // lets extract the XML from the HTTP response and return it.
        $response = preg_replace (
            '/
                \A       # Start of string
                .*?      # Match any number of characters (as few as possible)
                ^        # Start of line
                \r       # Carriage Return
                $        # End of line
             /smx',
            '', $http_response
        );
        return $response;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit perplexed: SOAP (being Simple Object Access Protocol) is totally opposite to live streaming. Every SOAP message is completely encapsulated: it has beginning and the end. It simply cannot be streamed.

You have mentioned some "new method" but you failed to give any details. "Live" updates may be achieved by repetitive requests or it may be actual data stream. If it is former: you can get away with SOAP but calling SOAP every second is not really good idea: remote server admin will not be happy with such onslaught. If it is latter: it cannot be SOAP. Period.

Unless you clarify what "new method" does and how it is invoked no one would be able to tell you how to solve your problem. But rest assured PHP these days capable of pretty much anything. So whatever issue you face you certainly don't need to change to some other programming language if you comfortable with PHP. I suggest you to amend your original question and add relevant details. I am sure you will find plenty of people here who would be able to give you exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things with your code:

1. You instantiate $client twice, so first $client is effectively overwritten.
2. Your SOAP header has only namespace argument.  It may not be required.

Your code appears to only register a session ID.  It's not apparent where the data is, maybe in another element of the $registered_string array?  I suspect there is more code you need to write after this.

Usually, in my experience, you would then use returned session ID to construct a URL.  You will then use that URL to access the data stream.  This would **NOT** be a SOAP call, but a normal web request using whatever method you prefer (e.g. `file_get_contents('http://example.com/blah?session=[SESSIONID]')`).  The server will use the session ID to authenticate you before returning data.

If this is how it works, then the answer is yes, you can access the data and insert it into the database, but only while the session ID is valid.  When session ID expires, you will have to call RegisterClient() again.  This will be true no matter what language you use.

Answer (score 0):

The Simple way could be to use websockets or even aync ajax request with timeout to your php soap file.

Answer (score -1):

**Bind a socket**

Function bind can be used to bind a socket to a particular address and port. It needs a sockaddr_in structure similar to connect function.

Quick example

```
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, "127.0.0.1" , 5000) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket bind OK \n";
```

Now that bind is done, its time to make the socket listen to connections. We bind a socket to a particular IP address and a certain port number. By doing this we ensure that all incoming data which is directed towards this port number is received by this application.

This makes it obvious that you cannot have 2 sockets bound to the same port. There are exceptions to this rule but we shall look into that in some other article.

**Listen for connections**

After binding a socket to a port the next thing we need to do is listen for connections. For this we need to put the socket in listening mode. Function `socket_listen` is used to put the socket in listening mode. Just add the following line after bind.

```
//listen
socket_listen ($sock , 10)
```

The second parameter of the function socket_listen is called backlog. It controls the number of incoming connections that are kept "waiting" if the program is already busy. So by specifying 10, it means that if 10 connections are already waiting to be processed, then the 11th connection request shall be rejected. This will be more clear after checking socket_accept.

Now comes the main part of accepting new connections.

**Accept connection**

Function `socket_accept` is used for this.

```
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, "127.0.0.1" , 5000) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket bind OK \n";

if(!socket_listen ($sock , 10))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket listen OK \n";

echo "Waiting for incoming connections... \n";

//Accept incoming connection - This is a blocking call
$client = socket_accept($sock);

//display information about the client who is connected
if(socket_getpeername($client , $address , $port))
{
    echo "Client $address : $port is now connected to us.";
}

socket_close($client);
socket_close($sock);
```

**Output**

Run the program. It should show
$ php /var/www/server.php
Socket created
Socket bind OK
Socket listen OK
Waiting for incoming connections...

So now this program is waiting for incoming connections on port 5000. Dont close this program , keep it running.
Now a client can connect to it on this port. We shall use the telnet client for testing this. Open a terminal and type
$ telnet localhost 5000

It will immediately show
$ telnet localhost 5000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

And the server output will show
Client 127.0.0.1 : 36689 is now connected to us.

So we can see that the client connected to the server. Try the above steps till you get it working perfect.

**Note**

The socket_getpeername function is used to get details about the client which is connected to the server via a particular socket.

Comment: How will this help me get the live contents of the SOAP call?

Comment: You can follow PHP reference, for better clarification on this. http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body.php

Comment: @NavnishBhardwaj How does the code you posted relate to "streaming a SOAP reponse" with a "timeout" and/or in an "interval"? What i see for now doesn't solve the problem and simply isn't an answer to the question. Please explain why your code is useful for the problem.